# how to trigger ngOnInit & service call in it using angular 4 testing

Tags: typescript

```
ngOnInit() { // this my onit function in dropdown.ts file
  this.getDivisions = [];
  this.service.getDivisions().subscribe(data =>{
    this.getDivisions = data;      
  }); 
}
```

// below is my second dropdown onchange function which gives me values depend on division i select from division dropdown

```
getRegionForSelectedDivision(selectedDivision) {
  this.selectedRegion = "Select Region";
  this.isDropdowndisabled = false;
  this.getRegions = this.selectedDivision.regionList;    
}
```

Actually i want to test this dependent dropdowns functionality in spec file using jasmine so how can I mock DataService in spec file to test it?

Comment: actually both functions are in same ts file & i want to write spec file based on it

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Have you tried anything? Read the documentation of jasmine on spies and mocks?

Comment: class mockDataService {
 getDivisions(){
    const divisions = [
      {"sbu":"Sales"},{"sbu":"Purchase"}  
    ]
    return divisions;   
  }
}it('should return divisions', () => {  // here m getting divisions undefined
    expect(this.divisions[0].sbu).toEqual('Ag & Turf');
    expect(this.divisions[1].sbu).toEqual('C&F');
  });